# 1994 Dodge Dakota V8, Antifreeze leaking from water pump

Tags: cooling-system, water-pump, water-leak

Every time I put ether antifreeze or water in my radiator it immediately comes out from beneath the water pump? What could cause that to happen?

Answer (score 4):

In most vehicles the seal on the water pump will fail when the bearings go bad, or something else bad happens to the pump.  Water leaking from the pump is almost always an indication that the pump is shot and needs to be replaced.

Of course, also check all your hoses for bursts or clamps that have come off.  The water might *look* like its coming from the pump if it's running down from a coincidental hole in a hose.